# How to create a new database in symfony for each user who registers?

Tags: database, symfony4

Using symfony4 i have a form registration and i want to create a database after every registration.

For example : i've name - company - email inputs.

After submitting i'll insert the data (ex : Jack,Jackstore,jack@store.com) in a database (db_user) after that i want to create automatically a new database (and entities) with the company name (db_jackstore)!

How could i do that ?

Comment: Down-voting this is pretty harsh, as there can be use cases where partitioning databases for individual use on additional devices / applications / security concerns are legitimate, especially if using SQLLite or MongoDB which kind-of lend themselves to this. Never say never. @Zaek I am looking into this at the moment & will let you know if I come up with a workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot.
Not with native symfony tool, or any external Bundle, i'm afraid.

Comment: Because it's sounds like a bad idea. I think you have to learn some stuff about RDBMS. You never want to create a new DATABASE for each user in your project.

Comment: the thing is that every user will have many clients ( many databases ) and i did it once in a project with pure php ! we r not talking about if it's a good/bad idea, i'm asking why it's not possible ! i know RDBMS my problem is that i'm a new in symfony.